# Ionic Notification/Push message

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, push-notification

I need to send a JSON containing the category and the message all users who have my application installed, like this:

```
{category:"shoes", message:"New pair of shoes available"}
```

then I need to **display a alert/notification only to users which checked a specific option** which matches the category in the JSON.

I'm using Ionic, NodeJS and Express. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Hello Shadow00,
>
> Then first of all you have to install FOUR Plugins for that.
>
> 1)cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
> // For notification
>
> 2)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
> // For on Device Ready to call
>
> 3)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
> // For notification Dialog
>
> 4)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
> // For Notification Sound
> ```

and generate API key and SenderId throw developer console.and senderid past in bellow code. And e.regid pass to on server.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pushNotification;

            function onDeviceReady() {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

                document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                    if( $("#home").length > 0)
                    {
                        // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                        //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        navigator.app.backHistory();
                    }
                }, false);

                try 
                { 
                    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
              $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
                    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                            device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"661780372179","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
                    } else {
                        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                    }
                }
                catch(err) 
                { 
                    txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                    txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                    alert(txt); 
                } 
            }

            // handle APNS notifications for iOS
            function onNotificationAPN(e) {
                if (e.alert) {
                     $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                     // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
                     navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
                }

                if (e.sound) {
                    // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                    snd.play();
                }

                if (e.badge) {
                    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
                }
            }

            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            function onNotification(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                        // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                        // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                        console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                        if (e.foreground)
                        {
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                                // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                                    // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                                    var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                                    // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                    // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                                    var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
                            my_media.play();
                        }
                        else
                        {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                            if (e.coldstart)
                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                            else
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        }

                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                        //android only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                        //amazon-fireos only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }

            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
            }

            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }

            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
         </script>
        <div id="home">
            <div id="app-status-div">
                <ul id="app-status-ul">
                    <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I going to try it later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK best of luck. and if you face any problem then tell me.

Comment: It worked! But now i need to subscribe to topics. Do you know how i could do that?

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmPubSub